# Mplayer fails to play network stream

Tags: arch-linux, streaming, mplayer, tls, youtube

I'm trying to play youtube streams with mplayer. On running `mplayer -cache 2048 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USUA_1WVM8I`, I get the following output and the video does not play at all.

```
MPlayer SVN-r37379 (C) 2000-2015 MPlayer Team
210 audio & 441 video codecs

Playing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USUA_1WVM8I.
libavformat version 56.25.101 (internal)
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Cache fill:  7.81% (163840 bytes)   [tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
Cache fill:  9.48% (198786 bytes)   
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.

[tls @ 0x7f75d89eaa00]
The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.

Exiting... (End of file)
```

The same thing happens for any other youtube video.

Looking at the output, it seems to be some problem with the TLS library, but I tried the same videos with VLC, and they played just fine. How can I solve this problem with mplayer?

Answer (score 1):

mplayer doesn't support the HTTPS protocol. So you should use mplayer in conjunction with youtube-dl to download the video in a framebuffer then play it.

Like this:

```
curl --ciphers RC4-SHA "$(youtube-dl -g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEVlyP4_11M)" | mplayer -
```

Comment: Or use [youtube-viewer](https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer).

Comment: Really? Here it tells me "https protocol not found, recompile with openssl or gnutls enabled." so it sounds like https can be enabled at compile time (but wasn't on my mplayer). mpv works (using youtube-dl internally).

Comment: You can try to recompile with GnuTLS. https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/41629?dev=10858

Comment: Was this solved? If so please mark it as solved, thank you.